# Lacking output strings when using function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, output

I'm having a problem with the below function:

```
ab<-matrix(c(1:20),nrow=4)
rownames(ab)<-c("a","b","c","d")
cd<-c("a","c")

test<-function(x,y,ID_Tag){
for(i in y) {
  M_scaled<-t(scale(t(x),center=T))           
  a<-quantile(M_scaled[match(i,rownames(x)),])
  assign(paste0("Probes_",ID_Tag,"_quan_",i),a)         
}
}

test(ab,cd,"C1")
```

x is the dataframe/matrix

y is the string I need to search for in rownames(x)

ID_Tag is is the number I use to distinguish my samples from each other.

The function is running, but no output is generated into strings afterwards.

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: Please provide some example input.

Comment: I've added some data that resembles the ones I work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `assign` within a function it will make the assignment to a variable that is accessible within that function only (i.e. it's like using `<-`). To get around this, you need to specify the `envir` argument in `assign` to be either the global environment `globalenv()` or the parent frame of the function. So try changing your `assign` statement to

```
assign(..., envir = parent.frame())
```

or

```
assign(..., envir = globalenv())
```

depending on what you want exactly (in the example you provided they are equivalent). Have a look at `?parent.frame` for more info on these. Another possibility is to specify the `pos` argument in `assign`, check `?assign`.

As an aside, assigning global objects from within a function can lead to various problems in general. I find it better practice in your example to return a list of objects created in the `for` loop rather than use assign.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wasn't aware of that, and with this you actually solved a lot of my problems!